# jsonschema2pojo maven plugin configuration in execution not considered

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jsonschema2pojo

I am trying to use the jsonschema2pojo plugin for generating POJOs based on both schema and json sourceTypes. The configurations are specified per execution. But every time the plugin is reporting **"One of sourceDirectory or sourcePaths must be provided"**. I am able to run it when the configuration is provided at the plugin level ( global ). But then I can only specify one sourceType.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-schema</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</outputEncoding>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <annotationStyle>jackson2</annotationStyle>
                            <generateBuilders>false</generateBuilders>
                            <initializeCollections>true</initializeCollections>
                            <refFragmentPathDelimiters>#/</refFragmentPathDelimiters>
                            <sourceType>jsonschema</sourceType>
                            <targetPackage>com.company.app.integration.sabre.stub.rest</targetPackage>
                            <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</sourceDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-json</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</outputEncoding>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <annotationStyle>jackson2</annotationStyle>
                            <generateBuilders>false</generateBuilders>
                            <initializeCollections>true</initializeCollections>
                            <refFragmentPathDelimiters>#/</refFragmentPathDelimiters>
                            <sourceType>json</sourceType>
                            <targetPackage>com.company.app.integration.sabre.stub.rest</targetPackage>
                            <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/json</sourceDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Is there any way to have the plugin use the configuration at execution level per goal ?

Plugin version: 0.5.1

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

When running the *'compile'* from Maven projects lifecycle, the plugin is considering the configuration from execution and is working as expected.

---

I am using Intellij and was trying to generate the pojo from Plugins -> jsonschema2pojo -> jsonschema2pojo:generate under 'Maven Projects' window. This was giving the above error and was not taking the configuration per execution.

When I run compile from the Maven Lifecycle, it is picking the configuration in the execution and is generating the files as specified.

I am not yet sure if this is a issue with the plugin or maven or if its a issue at all !!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your configuration out to the plugin level and using the parent folder (${baseDir}/src/main/resources) as the sourceDirectory.

Here's an old bug report describing the same thing:
https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/145

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That only takes care of the package creation for the subfolders. I wanted to have two different folders treated as jsonschema and json respectively.